# VLC can't connect to MiniDLNA

Tags: 20.04, vlc, minidlna

I installed the minidlna on a device connected to the local network and set it up. I'm able to play media from that device using VLC on iOS but VLC on Ubuntu 20.04 is unable to find it.

What I tried and doesn't work:

1. `$ vlc -v` Then Local Network -> Universal Plug'n'Play. It shows nothing, log:

```
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[000055b469eae670] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055b469f4c370] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007ff1287a55f0] upnp services discovery: Initializing libupnp on 'default' interface
[00007ff1287a55f0] upnp services discovery warning: search timeout
[00007ff1287a55f0] upnp services discovery warning: search timeout
```

2. `$ sudo gssdp-discover -i wlp3s0 --timeout=10`

```
Using network interface wlp3s0
Scanning for all resources
Showing "available" messages
```

3. Using kodi
4. Switching port in `/etc/minidlna.conf` to 9500, restarting minidlna service and turning off ufw as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/781747/211734), then trying steps 1–⁠3 again.

However when I open my_device_ip:9500 from this same Ubuntu machine in a browser, I can see the MiniDLNA status page.

**UPDATE:**

As @pasman pasmański [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377874/vlc-cant-connect-to-minidlna#comment2373748_1377874), it's seems to be the network settings issue. If I understand it correctly MiniDLNA is available to 192.168.1.0/24 only. Is it possible to set it to 192.168.0.0/16 instead?

Comment: DLNA works in VLC out of a box on Ubuntu 20.04. Check your server.

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box for me and since it works with iOS VLC I'm assuming the server is OK.

Comment: Maybe network settings are different ? What is the result of `ip a` , `ip r` ?

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, thanks. It seems minidlna is only available for 192.168.1.0/24 and I'm not in that range because I'm currently connected over the phone (USB tethering, the phone is connected to my Wi-Fi) because of a driver issue. I just tested it on Windows. Doesn't work with phone connection but works with direct Wi-Fi connection (Win driver is fine). Still unclear why the status is visible in the browser though on Ubuntu.